# Why Cygwin doesn't print what is being cloned from GitHub like Windows does? How to make it print?

Tags: github, windows-xp, cygwin

When I clone something from GitHub using Windows cmd it shows me the process. For example:

```
C:\sbox\git\clone>git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git
Cloning into 'ruby-build'...
remote: Counting objects: 1763, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (718/718), done.

Receiving objects: 100% (1763/1763), 197.13 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (958/958), done.
```

But when I do the same under Cygwin it doesn't show anything except the first line:

```
User@comp-123 /usr/local
$ git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git
Cloning into 'ruby-build'...
```

It creates the directory without any errors but how to make it to show the process? `-v` or `--verbose` options don't help. May it cause mistakes because for example `ruby-build` doesn't work?

Comment: Different version of git?

Comment: @bmargulies, No. I use the one and the same in Cygwin and in Windows. And it is installed here `C:\Program Files\Git`. Not under any Cygwin's directories.

Answer (score 2):

You've noted in the comments that you're using some Windows flavour of Git from Cygwin. This will cause problems because Cygwin terminals (ie MinTTY) don't look like terminals to non-Cygwin programs (which only expect the Windows command prompt). In particular, unless a program has been compiled specifically for Cygwin, it probably won't realise it can print stuff to screen.

You've two options to fix this. The easy one is to specify `--progress` to `git clone`. From the `git clone` man page (emphasis mine):

> `--progress`
>
> > Progress status is reported on the standard error stream by default **when it is attached to a terminal**, unless `-q` is specified. **This flag forcess progress status even if the standard error stream is not directed to a terminal**.

The better fix is to use Cygwin's Git. This knows exactly how to use Cygwin's terminal, so it will print to the terminal correctly in all circumstances without having to specify any arguments. It will also be able to get colours correct, which I imagine Windows Git will also be failing at in Cygwin.

You can install Cygwin Git from the standard Cygwin installer. [Download the Cygwin installer again](http://cygwin.com/install.html) if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

I would chalk this up to being an issue in versioning between the <strike>Ruby</strike> Git you have installed on Windows versus what is on Cygwin. My guess is that your Windows setup is using a 1.9 version of Git while Cygwin is on 1.8?

Comment: If fact I have installed Ruby1.9.3 with RailsInstaller (here `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3`) and do not have any other versions of Ruby neither under Cygwin nor in Windows. And I removed its path from `PATH` of Windows. So Cygwin doen't have to see it. May it still cause problems?

Comment: Ruby is completely irrelevant here; the fact that the code is Ruby should make no difference to the Git clone process.